# Deploy Azure SQL Elastic Database query

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have multiple Azure SQL databases. One database holds all the staging table and the other database holds all the fact/dim tables. Now in my development environment I have stored procedure which reads data from staging tables (from staging database) and loads the data into its respective fact/dim tables (in a different database).

The above scenario is all working fine. I have multiple SQL projects for each database.

Now how do I deploy the elastic database queries while deploying the dacpac?

Below is the error when I add the elastic queries as a part of my post deployment scripts in Visual studio and try to build it.

[image]

PS: The SQL project properties is set to target the V12 version of the Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully build, you will need to install the latest SSDT Preview which includes support for these objects from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429392). Support for the latest Azure SQL DB and SQL Server 2016 features is only available in the Preview for VS2013 at present, whereas for VS2015 the support was shipped in VS2015 Update 2. Once SQL Server 2016 goes GA (June 1, 2016) an RTM update will be pushed through the Visual Studio 2013 Extensions and Updates channel containing this support. That will ensure you get monthly updates with the latest changes again.

Note that even with the latest bits, if you open the file itself you'll get an issue with the Intellisense parser. Building the project will work fine but on opening a document you will see the errors appear for that specific document. Note that the same issue occurs in SSMS when coding this into a query window. This is because the Intellisense parser is separate from the core build system. The fix for this is in progress and will land in a post-SQL Server 2016 update (likely late June - July timeframe).

**Disclosure:** I work on the SQL Server tools team.

Comment: One more query. The dacpac deployment for V12 targeted database fails from PowerShell and also while manually deploying the dacpac from SSMS 2014. Will that also be fixed in the update so that I can safely deploy the dacpac's using PowerShell?

Comment: Given you use external data source, you need to use the latest SSMS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) to get support in the UI and to install the 130 version of SqlPackage.exe to deploy from the cmdline. SqlPackage.exe is installed by SSMS in the global location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin", and also by SSDT in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130". But since you're working with Azure, best thing is update to the new SSMS.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait for the RTM version since June is just around the corner :)

Answer (score 2):

Which version of the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) are you using? If you are not using the latest (14.0.60413.0), give it a try to upgrade SSDT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/mt429383. With that version, I am now successfully able to compile and publish database projects and dacpacs.

Comment: I am using the SSDT which comes specifically for VS2013. Are you using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Yes, I am using VS2015. VS2013 with the latest SSDT update might work as well (just guessing by the build numbering). But, I have not tried it. If you don't have access to VS2015, try the latest preview of SSDT for VS2013: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429392.

Comment: I have access to VS2015 (and yes it builds the dacpac successfully) but then my entire solution is build using 2013. I have updated SSDT for VS2013 but still it does not work. I wanted a solution which would work on 2013